# Wait until filter operation is complete in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a document list and want to search document based on name and do some operation using searched document. Below is the code

```
const searchDocumentListCSV: [] = this.defaultDocumentList.filter((element) => {
      return element.displayName.toLowerCase().includes('sampleDocument');
    });
   consol.log(searchDocumentListCSV)
```

but when i run the code 'searchDocumentListCSV' is empty as filter is async call.
Is there a way where code execution waits until the filter operation is complete

Comment: `filter` is not an async call. Maybe, it's because none of the elements match this condition: `element.displayName.toLowerCase().includes('sampleDocument')`

Comment: @NabinPaudyal you are right. There were no elements matching the display name as i was converting the display name into lower case and value that needs to be searched was not in lower case